# Hide localhost php path using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp, localhost

How can I hide my directory path using .htaccess I don'thave a idea on how to do it

example:

```
localhost/MainFolder/SubFolder/adminFolder/dashboard.php
```

and i want to see my url or the output something like this

```
localhost/MainFolder/SubFolder
```

Comment: You want to execute script inside `adminFolder/dashboard.php` when someone requests `MainFolder/SubFolder`?

Comment: yes something like that sir ..

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?MainFolder/SubFolder/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ /MainFolder/SubFolder/adminFolder/dashboard.php/?ir=true [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?MainFolder/SubFolder/adminFolder/dashboard.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^.*?ir=true.*$
RewriteRule ^.+$ /MainFolder/SubFolder/?ir=true [L,R=301,QSA]
```

**Demo**:

- When someone requests `http://localhost/MainFolder/SubFolder/adminFolder/dashboard.php`, then it would behave as shown here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=025f8c6d-b163-59c5-84d5-3f0fda163a6e
- When someone requests `http://localhost/MainFolder/SubFolder/`,then it would behave as shown here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=0072cd98-6259-5431-a3bb-65bf222bf247

In the above snippet, to avoid too many redirects issue, we are passing a query parameter internally to make sure that we don't end in a loop. If we find the parameter `ir=true`, no rule gets met and the code gets executed, else it works as intended by adding the query param `ir=true` and making the server realize you redirected from previous rewrite rule itself.

Best way to solve this would be avoid directory access permission to the `adminFolder` and have an index.php in `Subfolder` and call the `adminFolder/dashboard.php` using [require_once()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php).

Comment: btw where should i create the htaccess is it in the mainfolder?

Comment: @KIX You can create the `.htaccess` inside `MainFolder` and check.

Comment: http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/MainFolder/MainFolder/SubFolder/

i dont know but when i tried to get the code and redirect it shows me like that hmm

Comment: @KIX There was a missing `/` in my rule. I have updated my answer. You can try the entire code again.

Comment: oh there great thanks it works big help... its just i cant access my dashboard.php

Comment: @KIX You can't directly access it now from your browser because of the rules, or are you telling dashboard.php doesn't execute?

Comment: oh i see thats why do you have link like a cheatsheet code for rules in htaccess that i can learn on ...it just gives me a message on my page that the page ist working something like that

Comment: @KIx Offical documentation is your friend https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html. Also, does dashboard.php execute or not when you request `http://localhost/MainFolder/SubFolder/` ?

Comment: Could you share a screenshot? I hope folder structure is correct along with the file?

Comment: https://s1153.photobucket.com/user/xcast67/media/Capture.jpg.html

thats the output sir

Comment: @KIX ok, there seems to be problems with my rules. I will fix them.

Comment: @KIX I have updated my answer. Hope it solves your issue.

Comment: it works great thanks for helping me sir so much help sorry for late feedback

Comment: @KIX Good to hear. Can you please consider accepting it, so that others can also get a help and assurance that current solution works?